# Method 'System.Net.Logging.get_On' not found

Tags: c#, discord, missingmethodexception

I code, test and run my bot from the Visual Studio Community IDE

Whenever I start my discord bot on my mac (Macbook Pro, OSX Sierra) it stops at 
`await discord.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);`
with a `System.MissingMethodException` for a method called `System.Net.Logging.get_On`

`discord` is my DiscordSocketClient and `token` does get set to a valid token.

The bot does run perfectly fine on other computers.

Thanks in advance, I've looked everywhere but no one has ever heard of this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that all that was wrong was a old version of mono, install the latest version to fix.

Comment: which version should i download? I am using Mono 5.2.0.224, but still i am getting this error.

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this question? I'm running 5.4.0.201 and not sure how to solve the missing `System.Net.Logging.get_On` error.